# Inter host name resolving

Tags: java, ip, ip-address, host

I am trying to setup a [lily cluster](http://docs.ngdata.com/lily-docs-current/414-lily/432-lily.html) where in it talks about **Network Configuration** which I am unable to understand. But every time I try to run the server I get the following error. Kindly explain me the network configuration and how am I supposed to do this ?

> Network configuration
>
> Make sure your inter-host-nameresolving is set up correctly. The
>   hostnames should be properly set up: on each server, the local
>   hostname should resolve to the IP address of the network interface,
>   and reverse resolving the IP address should again give the same
>   hostname (and not localhost or the hostname with some domain suffix
>   appended to it).
>
> In Lily's bin directory you will find the tool lily-print-host which
>   will show you what Java detects as hostname and corresponding address.
>
> It is ok to fix this using /etc/hosts instead of changing DNS, but in
>   that case it should be done consistently on each node so that the
>   nodes know each other by name.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.lilyproject.server.modules.repository.BlobManagerSetup]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Response is null.; Host Details : local host is: "UG-BLR-L030/192.168.0.105"; destination host is: "localhost":54310; 
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Response is null.; Host Details : local host is: "UG-BLR-L030/192.168.0.105"; destination host is: "localhost":54310; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:760)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:83)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:803)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1332)
    at org.lilyproject.repository.impl.DFSBlobStoreAccess.<init>(DFSBlobStoreAccess.java:44)
    at org.lilyproject.server.modules.repository.BlobManagerSetup.<init>(BlobManagerSetup.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Response is null.
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveResponse(Client.java:941)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:836)
Startup failed. Will try to shutdown and exit.
[INFO ][00:34:55,387][main      ] org.lilyproject.runtime.info - Shutting down the modules.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because your hostnames are not properly set up. Particularly the **highlighted** text in the block-quote below:

> [...] reverse resolving the IP address should again give the same hostname (and **not localhost or the hostname with some domain suffix appended to it**).

---

"*To provide the comfort of tested and supported releases of the Hadoop stack, we have selected to use **Cloudera's** Hadoop distribution.*" - Third Paragraph from [Installing A Lily Cluster](http://docs.ngdata.com/lily-docs-current/414-lily/432-lily.html)

### The steps from [Cloudera - Configuring Network Names](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh5/v5-0-0/CDH5-Installation-Guide/cdh5ig_networknames_configure.html)

To ensure that the members of the cluster can communicate with each other, do the following on every system.

1. Set the hostname of each system to a unique name (not `localhost`). For example:

   `$ sudo hostname myhost-1`

   **Note:** This is a temporary measure only. The hostname set by `hostname` does not survive across reboots
2. Make sure the `/etc/hosts` file on each system contains the IP addresses and fully-qualified domain names (FQDN) of all the members of the cluster.

   **Important:**
   The canonical name of each host in `/etc/hosts` **must** be the FQDN (for example `myhost-1.mynet.myco.com`), not the unqualified hostname (for example `myhost-1`). The canonical name is the first entry after the IP address.

   If you are using DNS, storing this information in `/etc/hosts` is not required, but it is good practice.
3. Make sure the `/etc/sysconfig/network` file on each system contains the hostname you have just set (or verified) for that system, for example `myhost-1`.
4. Check that this system is consistently identified to the network:

   1. Run `uname -a` and check that the hostname matches the output of the `hostname` command.
   2. Run `/sbin/ifconfig` and note the value of `inet addr` in the `eth0` entry, for example:

      ```
      $ /sbin/ifconfig
      eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:A4:E8:97
                inet addr:172.29.82.176  Bcast:172.29.87.255
                Mask:255.255.248.0
      ...
      ```
   3. Run `` host -v -t A \`hostname` `` and make sure that hostname matches the output of the `hostname` command, and has the same IP address as reported by `ifconfig` for `eth0`; for example:

      ```
      $ host -v -t A `hostname`
      Trying "myhost.mynet.myco.com"
      ...
      ;; ANSWER SECTION:
      myhost.mynet.myco.com. 60 IN    A      172.29.82.176
      ```

---

Other helpful information follows...

### Best Practices for Cluster Network Configuration from [Hortonworks](http://hortonworks.com/kb/best-practices-for-cluster-network-configuration/)

> These are the best practices for configuring the network for a Hadoop cluster. These are recommended for a stable and performant Hadoop cluster.
>
> - Machines should be on an isolated network from the rest of the data center. This means that no other applications or nodes should share network I/O with the Hadoop infrastructure. This is recommended as Hadoop is I/O intensive, and all other interference should be removed for a performant cluster.
> - Machines should have static IPs. This will enable stability in the network configuration. If the network were configured with dynamic IPs, on a machine reboot or if the DNS lease were to expire then the machine’s IP address would change, and this would cause the Hadoop services to malfunction.
> - Reverse DNS should be setup. Reverse DNS ensures that a node’s hostname can be looked up through the IP address. Certain Hadoop functionalities utilize and require reverse DNS.

Comment: Why do I get this error ? `local host is: "UG-BLR-L030/192.168.0.105"; destination host is: "localhost":54310;`  `UG-BLR-L030` is my host name.

Comment: Also what should be my FQDN. For eg : If I am not connected to the internet , do i still need to provide FQDN and what should it be then ?